# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at Object.parse (native) at fromJson - AngularJS / cordova

Tags: php, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, http-post

I actually have here an http POST which should return a value in a JSON format at `then` function.

```
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://" + hostname + "/mobile/submit_order.php",
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log("submit order guest: " + res);
        //callback(res.data);
    }, function(response) {
        console.error("Submit order error 2: " + response);
    })
```

The console displays this message

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < at Object.parse (native) at fromJson 
 (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9892:14)
```

I know it is a PHP error returned in HTML format. The problem is this error message is not really visible. And another thing which I really wonder is when I try to give the `$_POST` an initial value which is same with the parameters I passed in http post method:

```
$_POST = json_decode('{  
       "user":{  
          "email":"magda.redd0000@gmail.com",
          "name":"Im a guest",
          "contact":"09169890198",
          "regcode":"3",
          "provcode":"308",
          "citymuncode":"30801",
          "brgycode":"30801001",
          "regdesc":"REGION III (CENTRAL LUZON)",
          "provdesc":"BATAAN",
          "citymundesc":"ABUCAY",
          "brgydesc":"Bangkal",
          "street":"dfdfsasdf  asdf sdf"
       }
    }', true);
```

and try to run it in web browser, it returns a fine JSON value.

```
{
     "success": true,
     "email_sent": 0,
     "generated_code": "03611561726",
     "type": "guest, cod"
}
```

This is the header and post parameter parser in PHP.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

//converts data to post
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($postData, true);
```

I wonder if there is any way to show the PHP error.

Comment: It should be inside your error handler in `response.data`, are you sure it is not there?

Comment: The error handler response doesn't have a value. This is the actual output : 
  `Submit order error 2: {}`

Comment: can you try changing `data: params` and delete headers?

Comment: The PHP error has shown when I removed the `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`. Thanks :)